# qTip - how to preserve its visibility after mouseover?

Tags: qtip

I use the qTip plugin, and if I move the cursor on the tooltip, it hides. Why ?

```
 $('.b-short-desc-div')
                  .hover(function () {
                          if ($(this).data("qtip")) $(this).qtip("destroy");

                          $(this) 
                            .qtip({
                                content: qTipContent,
                                position: { adjust: { x: -160, y: -15 } },
                                show: {
                                    when: false,
                                    ready: true
                                },
                                hide: false,
                                style: {
                                    border: {
                                        width: 5,
                                        radius: 10
                                    },
                                    padding: 10,
                                    textAlign: 'center',
                                    tip: true,
                                    name: 'cream'
                                }
                            });
                  }, function () { $(this).qtip("destroy"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `fixed: true` in your `hide` tag ([as shown here](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/hide/#fixed))